# Integer solution of $x^5+31=y^2$

Tags: number-theory

Does the equation $x^5+31=y^2$ has no solution in integers $x,y$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it as $x^5+32=y^2+1$. See $x$ cannot be even. Then $32$ divides LHS but RHS can be divisible by at most $2$. Now $x^5+32=(x+2)(x^4-2x^3+4x^2-8x+16)$. Now if $x\equiv 1\pmod 4$ then $x+2\equiv -1\pmod 4$ implying it has a prime factor of the form $4k-1$. But since $x+2\mid y^2+1$ we have a contradiction. If $x\equiv -1\pmod 4$ then second factor is $\equiv -1 \pmod 4$ and from previous logic we have a contradiction. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Looking at your first line "See x cannot be even" it is not immediately obvious unless one knows to look at the equation mod 4, since a simple check of "if y is odd" simply returns "x must be even". After that however it is very insightful

Comment: I wrote in the next sentence that then "32 divides LHS...." did you read that part? I thought that was explanation enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes I did. Still I feel that it worth mentioning that without much thinking, looking at the equation $\mod 4$ can reveal the same detail

Comment: Yes, well I was being lazy you got me there. :P